# Alternatives to ordinary fenders

Tags: fenders

I ride a fixie and fenders just don't look good on it. Rear fender is ok, but there is no way I'm installing such a monstrosity on the front wheel. Are there any alternative out there that don't make make shoes soaking wet after a few turns?

I've seen interesting approach done on a [Denny](http://oregonmanifest.com/and-the-winner-isdenny/) bike that won [The Bike Design Project](http://oregonmanifest.com/). Is a brush that constantly contacts the tire a good approach?

Comment: In the past there have been a variety of splash guards, such as, eg, a piece of plastic about 4" wide and 12" long that mounts on the down tube.  I don't know if such is available today, though.

Comment: Given you are asking about a fixie and therefore expecting form over function all I can suggest is waiting till the road is dry at the local, sipping cafe'latte's or waterproof shoes could be an option, but they are mostly as ugly as the fenders that you object to. Spray waterproofing on your existing shoes could work for a short time.

Comment: Or shoe covers.

Comment: Down tube mounted mudguards as mentioned by @danielrhicks are sold for mountain bikes - crud catcher and cheaper imitations. They're IME of limited benefit when travelling in a straight line and none at all if you end up going through puddles on even the slightest bend.

Comment: Yeah, the downtube guards are mostly to stop light rain spray, as when you go out shortly after the rain has stopped.  Would do little good if you're actually riding in the rain.  Even full-on fenders will not keep your feet dry then.

Comment: To me, the idea of a brush that sweeps the water off has a couple problems, even if it does work.  It will add resistance.  If the resistance isn't high enough, then water won't be brushed away.  If resistance is too high it will slow you down too much. They aren't that popular and I imagine you'd need to replace the brush quite often as its' going to be constantly worn away by your tire.  There's going to be increased wear on your tires, how much, I'm not sure. And, they probably wouldn't work on anything that isn't a slick because it wouldn't get in all the grooves to get the water out.

Answer (score 2):

Plastic fenders, yeah I would agree with you that they don't look good on a fixie.

However, I think metal is the perfect match for a fixie.  Might wanna consider Velo Orange.